# Convert Date format in shell

Tags: shell, date, unix, data-conversion

Is there a function in shell that converts date from one format to another.
For eg. I want to convert the following `PST` to `CST`

```
2016-11-30 15:55:10-08:00
```

to

```
2016-11-30 17:55:10-06:00
```

Comment: Check this link - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-can-i-have-date-output-the-time-from-a-different-timezone

Answer (score 1):

Not in shell per se, but there is [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) and with that it's trivial:

```
$ dateconv '2016-11-30 15:55:10-08:00' -z CST6CDT
2016-11-30T17:55:10
```

The actual zone names (following `-z`) should be the ones you installed in /usr/share/zoneinfo/, so equivalently you could use:

```
$ dateconv '2016-11-30 15:55:10' --from-zone America/Los_Angeles --zone America/Chicago
2016-11-30T17:55:10
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.